# mark message as unseen using Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap, zend-mail

i'm using `Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap` to ream emails.

In some special case, after iv'e read the message, i want to mark it as unread again.

how can i do that in zend framework?

Thanks,
Boris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't have access to the code I used this in, but something along the lines of the following rings a bell:

```
foreach ($mail as $message_id => $message) {
    $mail->setFlags(
        $mail->getNumberByUniqueId($mail->getUniqueId($message_id)),
        array(Zend_Mail_Storage::FLAG_RECENT)
    );
}
```

Comment: Aren't just `$message_id` like `$mail->setFlags($message_id, array(Zend_Mail_Storage::FLAG_RECENT));` not enough?